# How to find the cpu utilization(%) of a java class

Tags: java, profiling

Need an agent/java program that queries JVM and find the cpu utilization(%) of a java class and methods running in it .

Comment: Those programs are called profilers - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/please-recommend-a-java-profiler

Comment: Google [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/).

Comment: Use [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) and [TPTP profiler](http://www.deepakgaikwad.net/index.php/2009/02/10/tutorialprofiling-with-tptp-and-tomcat.html)

Answer (score 3):

It worth noting that classes and methods don't use CPU (except when loaded or compiled) and the time it takes to do this is usually not very interesting.

Threads use CPU and they spend different amounts of time in different methods. (Again trying to see how much time is spent in a class is unlikely to be useful)

To do this you can use a CPU profiler, assuming you have a performance problem you are trying to diagnose.  Unless you have a performance issue, this is unlikely to be useful. Sometimes a profiler can show you a program appears to be behaving correctly for the wrong reasons, but this is rare.

Another tool which is useful is using a memory profiler and it can be the real cause of your problem.

Often performance problems are due to the speed of you disk, network or some other IO device.  In this case, a profiler isn't going to show you much so its useful to have some idea what the problem is and its likely cause before you start using a profiler.

Comment: I want to create my own profiler...so need a java code for finding the CPU utilization of each method or thread inside in the method what ever may be...